# Get an element by its ref in vue and give it focus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to give focus to a vue input when a button is pressed. My understanding is that I need the html element, which I get by setting a ref value, then saying:

```
this.$refs.theRefName.$el.focus();
```

But I'm getting tripped up on the `refs` part of that expression. See the MRE below where `refs` contains the correct keys, but the values are empty.  As a result `.$el` is undefined and the expression errs.

I've seen SO articles that deal with `this` being undefined (not a problem for me) or `$refs` being empty because the element was conditionally rendered (also, not a problem for me). I've got `$refs`, but why does it contain empty objects?

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'World'
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.$refs))
      // here's what I want to do, but I can't because inp2 is empty
      // this.$refs.inp2.$el.focus();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Why are refs empty objects?</h1>
  <input ref="inp1"></input><br/><br/>
  <input ref="inp2" placeholder="i want focus on click"></input><br/><br/>
  <button @click="click">Click me</button>
</div>
```

If you can help me get to the html element and give it focus, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: I've had issues before with focusing elements with javascript. Do you have the dev tools open? If so, try closing them and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks @dantheman, I am running with dev tools open, but couldn't see any behavior change when I closed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without $el :

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'World'
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.$refs.inp2.focus();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Why are refs empty objects?</h1>
  <input ref="inp1" /><br/><br/>
  <b-form-input ref="inp2" placeholder="i want focus on click"></b-form-input>
  <button @click="click">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you help him: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73281247/19549267

Comment: Thank you. Well, this is pretty confusing, because there's no doubt your suggestion works, but (1) can you explain why logging `this.$refs.inp2` logs `{}`?  sending the focus method to {} seems like it shouldn't work.  (2) when I try  your idea on my real code, it fails I think because I'm using a bootstrap-vue input which really hides the input element inside of it.

Comment: It seems like the wrapping component does implement focus, but I'm still seeing an empty object and bad behavior.  https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#input-methods

Comment: @goodson hey mate I updated my answer with bootstrap-vue input component, take a look pls

Comment: Thanks @NikolaPavicevic.  I'm going to mark this correct and continue to puzzle over why my (almost the same) code doesn't work.   I might post another question later and ask for your help.  ...possibly having to do with this stuff embedded in an input group.

Comment: @NikolaPavicevic, you've been so helpful on other questions... I wonder if you'd mind having a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364733/bootstrap-vue-table-how-to-remove-row-with-animation